# iText7: How to add text to the bottom of last page?

Tags: java, itext7

I am new to iText7, and I want to add a text after the content in the last page. I basically got a pdf file and create a new one, copying the pages from the first into the last. After, I get the last page and tried to append some text:

```
PdfPage lastPage = pdfOut.getLastPage();
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(lastPage.newContentStreamAfter(), lastPage.getResources(), pdfOut);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().add(new Text("Este documento foi assinado Hoje"));

Canvas c = new Canvas(canvas, pdfOut, rect);
c.add(paragraph);
c.close();
```

The text is not being appended after the content, sometimes appears in the first line of the last page or even it is not shown. Some ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's definition of `rect` in the code? Despite this uncertainty below snippet should work

```java
final Rectangle canvasSize = document.getPageEffectiveArea(new PageSize(lastPage.getPageSize()));
Canvas c = new Canvas(canvas, pdfOut, canvasSize);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph()
        .add(new Text("Este documento foi assinado Hoje"))
        .setHeight(canvasSize.getHeight())
        .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked in some documents, but if int the last page the content fills the entire page, the new paragraph is not shown.